# Proper way of closing a thread using start_new_thread

Tags: python, multithreading

Inherited a project that is using pythons old thread module. At some point in the future I will switch over to threading however at the moment I work with what I got. What is the proper way of closing a thread using start_new_thread. Here is my current code:

```
ac_thread = start_new_thread(get_token_every_two_minutes, (driver.current_url, q))
time.sleep(20)
ac_thread.exit()
```

The exception I get is:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function thread_flow at 0x0396CB30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\common_functions.py", line 609, in thread_flow
ac_thread.exit()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'exit'
```

Per the thread documentation start_new_thread should return an identifier and 
thread.exit():

```
Raise the SystemExit exception. When not caught, this will cause the thread to exit silently.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc of [thread.start_new_thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) says:

> **Start a new thread and return its identifier.**

This identifier is an `int`, which of course doesn't have 'exit' attribute.

Regarding closing the thread; the thread will either silently exits (after finishing) or when the function terminates with an unhandled exception, a stack trace is printed and then the thread exits.